# ValueError: could not convert string to float: python pandans

Tags: python, dataframe, object, floating-point, type-conversion

I am trying to convert the all the cells value (except date) to float point number, but I'm getting and

error:
Can only use .str accessor with string values!
[image]

here is my code:

```
df['Market Cap_'+str(coin)] = df['Market Cap_'+str(coin)].str.replace(',','').str.replace('$', '').astype(float)
        df['Volume_'+str(coin)] = df['Volume_'+str(coin)].str.replace(',','').str.replace('$', '').astype(float)
        df['Open_'+str(coin)] = df['Open_'+str(coin)].str.replace(',','').str.replace('$', '').astype(float) 
        df['Close_'+str(coin)] = df['Close_'+str(coin)].str.replace(',','').str.replace('$', '').astype(float)
```

here is the output of df.info()

> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
> Int64Index: 30 entries, 1 to 30
> Data columns (total 5 columns):

## Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype

---

0   Date_ETHEREUM        30 non-null     datetime64[ns]
1   Market Cap_ETHEREUM  30 non-null     float64
2   Volume_ETHEREUM      30 non-null     float64
3   Open_ETHEREUM        30 non-null     float64
4   Close_ETHEREUM       30 non-null     object
dtypes: datetime64ns, float64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 1.4+ KB
here is an image of my dataframe:

[image]

Note: Coin is just a string which added dynamically from URL for each particular coin table.

I would appreciate any help or an alternative solution.

Comment: You need to remove the `$` from the values in that column before trying to parse it as a floating point number.

Comment: I changed my code according your answer and getting an error, please check

Comment: but its converted

Comment: I have updated my question. Getting an error on last column,

Answer (score 2):

You have a $ sign so the value cannot be parsed as a float. Remove it before converting the column to a float type

Comment: I changed my code according your answer and getting an error, please check

Comment: Your edit shows a warning now, not an error, is there a problem with the convertion?

Comment: updated my question; I was able to convert first three, but getting an error on last one as it is shown in question

Comment: @RoxanaSlj please add full error output including line number and which line failed